# CXF wsdl2java: No adress location in wsdl:port tag

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf, jax-ws

When creating a web-service using CXF (configuration in Spring), my resulting WSDL is missing the address location in port tag. This is problematic for client side. If CXF is used for client creation, endpoint must be set programatically in client code. If Axis is used (the consumer of my web-service wants to be able to use Axis 1), there is an error saying

```
Error in generating Java from WSDL:  java.io.IOException: 
Emitter failure.  Cannot find endpoint address in port FooServiceSOAPPort 
in service FooServiceLocator
```

Instead of being forced to create the client using CXF or Axis2 and manually setting the endpoint in client code, I would like to have the following child element:

```
<soap:address location="http://localhost:9000/services/foo"/>
```

under the tag `<wsdl:port binding="..." name="...>` in my WSDL (generated by CXF from my service code).

If I save the WSDL as local file and I manually add the line above, client is generated without any problems using Axis, no manual endpoint setting is needed on the client side and everything is OK. So, **how do I make the address location line appear in WSDL generated by CXF?**

Here's my Spring config (relevant endpoint tag):

```
<jaxws:endpoint xmlns:hel="http://user.services/"
    name="Foo"
    address="/services/foo"
    implementor="services.foo.FooImpl"/>
```

Here's my service interface:

```
@WebService
public interface Foo {
    String method1(String arg1);
}
```

and implementation

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "services.foo.Foo")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT, use = Use.LITERAL)
public class FooImpl implements Foo {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "method1")
    public String method1(String arg1) {
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `publishedEndpointUrl` property in jaxws:endpoint should be the one to do the trick, but I can't get it to work. Perhaps I missed something... All I want is to have the `<soap:address location="...">` in my generated WSDL using CXF.

Answer (score 0):

My first question is how you are generating the WSDL file. Using Ant or Maven. If you are using Maven following will solve your problem.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process-classes</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <className>com.stackoverflow.cxf.HelloWorld</className>
                        <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <address>http://localhost:9999/blah/blah</address>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java2ws</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

in the `<address>` you can specify the one you want. If you are using java2ws command line tool (provided by cxf) you can specify the same using -address command line argument. [CXF java2ws tool](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/java-to-ws.html). I tried this using CXF version 2.5.9. generating sample web service and following is the snippet of resulting wsdl.

```
  <wsdl:service name="HelloWorldService">
    <wsdl:port name="HelloWorldPort" binding="tns:HelloWorldServiceSoapBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost9999/blah/blah"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't use neither Ant nor Maven, my endpoint definition is done in CXF's configuration file (which is basically a Spring config file). Here's the relevant part: 

    `<import resource="classpath:cxf.xml"/>

    <jaxws:endpoint xmlns:hel="http://user.services/"
        name="Foo"
        address="/services/foo"
        implementor="services.foo.Foo"
    />`

Comment: Hi could you please tell me, how you retrieve/generates wsdl. Through build tool or from server ?

Comment: My web-service is deployed automatically by CXF. The standard procedure would be this http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html , but since I'm building a Play! application, I followed this tutorial (same principle, but a little different implementation due to lack of support for SOAP in Play! - please don't ask why do I even need SOAP) http://www.imind.eu/web/2013/11/07/developing-soap-services-using-play-framework-2-2-x/

Comment: In your question above you wrote "my resulting WSDL" , I am curious to know how to end up getting wsdl ?. I never used Scala so this question will give me some insight of your problem.

Comment: Since I'm using Play! framework (but in Java, not Scala), I use this module in order to be able to use CXF. https://github.com/imindeu/play-cxf

Comment: Sorry , I can not help you further because to replicate the issue on my PC I will have to learn Play framework. But for a short note : I have been developing web service using Java and CXF since last three years and I generate wsdl through Option 1 build tool (maven or ant) Option 2 (using cxf wsld2java command line tool) Option 3 - (is used most of the time ) from server when web service is deployed and developer can retrieve wsdl using url http://<host>:<port>/<context>/<service name>?wsdl . I hope some one from Scala world will notice your question and put you in right direction.